# find element with max value from std::map

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I'm trying to get the element with max value from std::map,

```
int main() {
    map<int, int> m;
    m[1] = 100;
    m[2] = -1;

    auto x = std::max_element(m.begin(), m.end(), m.value_comp());

    cout << x->first << " : " << x->second << endl;
}
```

why it prints the second element `2 : -1` ?

Comment: Hmmm... `std::max_element()` seems to be comparing the keys of the map

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/value_comp

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371137/2636457):

```
auto x = std::max_element(m.begin(), m.end(),
    [](const pair<int, int>& p1, const pair<int, int>& p2) {
        return p1.second < p2.second; });
```

This, rather than using `std::map::value_comp()` (which compares the key values) looks at the `second` member in the pair, which contains the value. This uses a lambda expression, so you will have to compile with C++11 support

Comment: I agree with this answer. It could be written a bit more generic, though. If you know `m` is of type `M`, you might write `[](const M::value_type& p1, const M::value_type& p2)`. It is robust to type changes in `M` but has an unnecessary indirection here

Answer (score 5):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/value_comp/

```
Returns a comparison object that can be used to compare two elements to get whether
the key of the first one goes before the second.
```

and 2 > 1. `value_comp` compares the **key** values, not the value values. Because that's how C++ rolls.