# Why "auto" is not acceptable as lambda parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto

Why does this code make a compile error?

```
std::find_if(std::begin(some_list), std::end(some_list), [](const auto& item){
//some code
});
```

The error of course at "auto"? why is not possible to know the type automatically ?
thanks

Comment: It *is* possible, but it's not part of C++11. It is however a part of [the C++14 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Generic_lambdas).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks.. I have not read anything about C++ 14 version yet. However, this nice ability is enough for me to move on!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because as of C++11, lambda functions in C++ cannot be defined  generically, therefore you cannot declare a parameter using `auto`. This has been added in the C++14 (and is already supported by some compilers).

However, you can achieve the same thing in C++11 using `decltype()`, in you case:

```
std::find_if(std::begin(some_list), std::end(some_list), [](decltype(*some_list.begin())& item){
        return item > 4;
```

Comment: Thanks,  is decltype something at compile or runtime ?

Comment: "This will be added in the C++14" Well, C++14 *is* the latest C++ standard.

Comment: @black True, changed the wording.

Comment: "cannot not" tend to cancel each other!