# How do I get the max element of a std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map

I know how to retrieve the maximum element of a `std::map` through the use of `std::max_element`, but I am unable to achieve the same affect with a `std::unordered_map` due to the differences between the container types.

**How can I find the maximum value in a `std::unordered_map` and return the corresponding `std::pair`?**

My current method for doing this with a `std::map` is shown (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34937216/7706917)). I can't seem to figure out how to do the same for a `std::unordered_map`.

```cpp
template <typename KEY_T, typename VALUE_T>
std::pair<KEY_T, VALUE_T> findMaxValuePair(
    std::map<KEY_T, VALUE_T> const &x)
{
    return *std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end(),
                             [](const std::pair<KEY_T, VALUE_T> &p1,
                                const std::pair<KEY_T, VALUE_T> &p2)
                             {
                                 return p1.second < p2.second;
                             });
}
```

When I attempt to use the above function on a `std::unorderd_map` (replacing `std::map` with `std::unordered_map`, I receive a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: And what happens when you simply replace `std::map` with `std::unordered_map`, here?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` occurs.

Comment: @paddycakes -- Then you need to post a [mcve].  We have no idea where, when, or how you're calling this function.

Comment: This must be due to some other unrelated problem with the code; but unfortunately it's not possible to figure out what is the problem with some code that's not shown; but only with code that's shown and meets all requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: @paddycakes Also, in all likelihood, your `std::map` version is hiding the bug.  You should be glad `unordered_map` uncovered it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Making the code work for `unordered_map`

In this case, we can actually do it just by changing the type from `map` to `unordered_map`.

**Before:**

```
template <class Key, class Value>
std::pair<Key, Value> findMaxValuePair(
    std::map<Key, Value> const &x)
{
    return *std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end(),
                             [](const std::pair<Key, Value> &p1,
                                const std::pair<Key, Value> &p2)
                             {
                                 return p1.second < p2.second;
                             });
}
```

**After:** we changed the type to `unordered_map`.

```
template <class Key, class Value>
std::pair<Key, Value> findMaxValuePair(
    std::unordered_map<Key, Value> const &x)
{
    return *std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end(),
                             [](const std::pair<Key, Value> &p1,
                                const std::pair<Key, Value> &p2)
                             {
                                 return p1.second < p2.second;
                             });
}
```

#### Making the code work for both

We can write a function that works with all of the standard containers really simply! This will work for maps, vectors, lists, and pretty much everything else that defines `begin()`, `end()`, and `value_type`!

```
template <class Container>
auto findMaxValuePair(Container const &x)
    -> typename Container::value_type
{
    using value_t = typename Container::value_type;
    const auto compare = [](value_t const &p1, value_t const &p2)
    {
        return p1.second < p2.second;
    };
    return *std::max_element(x.begin(), x.end(), compare);
}
```

#### What about the [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)?

This code may segmentation fault if the map or container is empty, either because you're accessing memory you don't own; because the memory pointed to by `map::end()` contains garbage that you then try to construct something like a string out of, or because it's represented as a null pointer.

For maps in particular, if there's memory corruption, that could also result in a segmentation fault, although that would be true independent of how you tried iterating through the map.

Comment: I'm sure OP has thought of that (which you can read in the question's comment section).

Comment: The segfault is an issue unrelated to the algorithm used to find the maximum element, but I updated my answer to address the possible reasons

Comment: As you suggested. The segfault occured due to the map being empty. A `if(x.size() ==0) return Container::value_type();` check accounted for the issue.

Comment: Ok! Glad to hear that!

Comment: @paddy returning a flag value on empty or error is a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakk The flag value is favored over other exception handling as no error is thrown and the entire program should not crash due to an empty container.

Comment: @paddycakes See `expected` or `optional`.  Or, return a non-owning possibly-null pointer to the element.  None of these are flag values.

Answer (score 0):

An ordered map , as the name says, is ordered, but by the key. Here you are aiming for the values.

In either case you would need to iterate through the whole map in order to find the maximum value. An ordered map can efficiently find the maximum or minimum keys, but not the values. So a full-scan approach taken will work both for an unordered or ordered maps.

If you need to efficiently find the max values you might consider changing your code to use an ordered set, reverse ordered map (value vs key) or ordered bag (multi-value map for the same key)

Comment: What do you mean by *"but the key"*?