# Counting no. of characters in string using map in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I have seen many solutions to character counting and keeping track of the max. occurrence char using arrays and vectors but I am looking for implementation of map in c++ to do the same and I am stuck at the thing that map if defined like

```
map<int, int> mp; 
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
     mp[a[i]]++;
```

So, If we write this then this will this give the keys as the count of the char if I used so, Is there a direct method or function which can find the max. value in map without looping over it.

```
map<char ,int> mp;
```

How can I use the map in c++ to find the max. occurrence of the char in the given string?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you show?

Comment: you found a solution and now you want to know if this really is a solution? Did you try to use it?

Comment: What charset are you working with? If it's just unsigned chars, your code will be faster by using an `std::array<int,256> mp;` instead of `std::map<unsigned char, int> mp;` (you can use it pretty much the same as the map in your scenario)

Comment: keys are the characters (stored as `int`) and the values are the counts, otherwise the code does what you want. "or if not..." why do you have doubts? Your question is rather unclear

Comment: How can I go for the max count the char or simply how do I access that particular element  with max. counts in maps.I am stuck how to hardcode or accessing the max. count values from the map I created .

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit more clear, you should include a complete example of your code ([mcve]). Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370945/c-help-finding-the-max-value-in-a-map/9371137

Comment: Oh , thanks that question cleared my doubts.